# Using ORM exception to display "username is taken" error message in registration

Tags: php, symfony, exception, doctrine

I have a dilemma about how to handle registration situation when username is already taken. I have 2 solutions:

1. Try to persist new user, catch `UniqueConstraintViolationException` and display error message.
2. Perform SQL query that will check if username exists, if it does, dont execute persist query, just display error message.

Second solution seems more appropriate, but it performs additional query so I have impact in performance (that's no big deal because its registration so its going to be executed only once per user).

I have most doubts because second solution require more code to be written then first one - everyone knows less code is better.

Comment: Basically they are the same as performance would never impact in a situation like this.

I suppose there's not a correct answer or a best practice one. 

What I would do is to us the first as I don't ever need to change the query if I add some others unique constraints or if I change one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use database constraints to check your own business requirements. I'd strongly recommend to create your own "unique constraint" and check it with the rest form validations (like username length, password strength etc.).

Following the great principle "Don't reinvent the wheel", I'd suggest to check well-known bundles:

1. [Symfony Constraints](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/constraints.html) - documentation about using constraints
2. [FOS User Bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle)  - great bundle, which provides functional user system